# Trouble with the variation path of an image

Tags: image, smoothing, after-effects

First, sorry for my english, I am french...

Well, I would like to move a picture only in x for example.

```
996 - 508 though 1392 - 508 (x-y)
```

after smooth the curves, I have a variation in y ... And I don't know how to solve it :

[image]

Someone can help me? 
thx

Comment: Try to separate the position attribute in 2 dimension and smooth only the x property. This will solve this problem. This occurs a lot in After Effects, the only way to fix it is to remove the bezier on the keys. But since the x and the y are merged together, you have to seperate them to get a proper smooth.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how can I separate the position attribute in 2 dimension?

Comment: In code or in the software ? In the software just press right click or shift-right click on the property position and press "separate the dimensions"

Comment: Ahah in the software ! ;) 
Ok thanks a lot, its work !